# How to recreate the Material Design Speed Dial animation from the FAB in Compose?

Tags: material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to recreate the animation for the expanded Speed Dial shown on the [Material Design website](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button#types-of-transitions) but I'm struggling to achieve the exact same result in Compose. For now I tried to play with the `AnimatedVisibility` of the `ColumnScope` but I don't thin it's possible to replicate the same behavior.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the expected output by using Floating Action Button Speed Dial library.

The library is available on Jcenter so no additonal repository is required.

Check whether you get the desired result https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial.

Comment: I'm the developer of that library :-) I'm trying to create a Compose version of it but I don't know how to do that animation in Compose.

Comment: Well, I ended up implementing it into my library so, I guess, yours can now be considered the right answer :-)
Source code available [here](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/blob/f0234c4552da6290f62c7a9d1987788fa4473f32/library-compose/src/main/kotlin/com/leinardi/android/speeddial/compose/SpeedDial.kt#L92)

Answer (score 0):

It can definitely be achieved, that's for sure. One method that I can think of currently is something like this:

Create a single Composable that accepts a state (shown/hidden) and any other parameters you require. Inside that, create a state-holder for the visibility of each dial item, and trigger the animation on them at certain millis apart from each other.

Something like this

```
@Composable
fun SpeedDial(expanded: Boolean){
 LaunchedEffect(expanded){
  handleAnimation()
 }

 val visibilityList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Boolean>(/* List Of Booleans */) }
 AnimatedVisibility(visible == visibilityList(0)){
  Item1() // Visible only if the first item in list is visible
 } 

 // Copy-paste for other items

 suspend fun handleAnimation() {
  visibilityList.forEachIndexed { index, visibility ->
    visibilityList.set(index, expanded)
    delay(150) // Alter per-requirement
  }
 }

}
```

This should achieve the effect without lag. Try it out.

Comment: Initialize the list with as many Booleans as there are items in your speed dial. You should initialize its every index with value of `expanded` received currently. It will not be re-initialized with that because of `remember`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the suggestion but I found out that some `animationSpec` of `AnimatedVisibility`, like `tween` can take a `delayMillis` and that can be used to delay the animations without the need to do it directly with coroutine.

Comment: Well as long as the problem was resolved, cheers.